# Modelling "I'm a * but I'm also a **"

Tags: c#, oop, entity-framework, design-patterns, inheritance

In [[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327939/options-for-class-design-using-safe-downcasting)], I'm struggling to implement a State Pattern as @jonp suggests.  I don't quite get how to use what's he's posted but it leads to the thought that maybe I'm trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.  So my question:

If I have a visitor to my site that can play multiple roles i.e. a `User` could be a `Vendor`, an `Employer`, an `Advertiser`, OR all of the above, should I be using inheritance?  I've declared:

```
class Vendor : User {}
class Advertiser : User {}
```

et cetera, but when a user is both a vendor and an employer then instances of different classes really point to the same underlying object... I'm not sure this can work.  How do I model it?

*** update ***

thanks everyone (you all get a point (it's all I can give)).  I've been pulling my hair out over deep-copies with EF, downcasting and the state pattern for the last several days.  The role approach makes much more sense.

Comment: Perhaps I can interest you in C++, a language with arbitrary inheritance? ;-)

Comment: @Kerrek C++ doesn't provide much help with dynamically creating a unique User subtype that inherits a dynamic set of roles based on what's read from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a situation to which the **attribute pattern** (or so I call it) would be very appropriate. It's a much more loosely-coupled approach than simple inheritance that can be used to specify multiple "behaviours" or in your case kinds of `User`. It's really nothing more complicated than an object having tags of another kind of object.

The easiest way to implement it would be to have a concrete `User` class, with a read-only property `IList<UserRole>` (internally this can be a `List<T>` field perhaps). Your `UserRole` class would then be abstract, and `VendorRole`/`AdvertiserRole`/etc. would derive from it, allowing you to tag on an arbitrary number of different roles (even ones of the same type) onto a given user. These roles can in addition define their own custom behaviours, utility methods, etc.

In addition, you could define a `GetRole<TRole>` method on your `User` class to facilitate access to roles of a specific type (assuming each `User` only has a single `Role` of a specific subtype).

Side note: you may also consider the [**decorator patern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), which is closely related to the above mentioned pattern -- though personally I feel it is overkill here, and really adds nothing in terms of flexibility or power. It often just obscures what you're trying to do; though feel free to investigate anyway.

Comment: Is this a decorator?  It looks to me more like a bog-standard polymorphic collection scenario, or possibly multiple 1:0-1 references.

Comment: @Jeffrey: You're right, it's not quite the decorator pattern, but it's a more sensible/simpler approach that is just as powerful here. :-)

Comment: Just update my answer actually... I've noted that the decorator pattern is clearly closely related, but slightly more involved.

Comment: I've seen this called the [capability pattern](http://www.java.net/blog/timboudreau/archive/2008/08/the_capability.html).  Basically, it allows your objects to act under several interfaces by either directly implementing them or returning a member that implements them.

Comment: @Ryan: Good to know. I still think I prefer my name though... it's more transparent. ;)

Comment: @Ryan The capability pattern? ... *(reads page)* ... Oh, you mean the Java crew's discovered there was a point to http://goo.gl/zm2qf besides implementing objects in C.  (I used Java from 1.1 through 1.4 before deciding they'd lost the plot by trying to copy C#.)

Answer (score 3):

You should favor **Composition over Inheritance** if the different roles have to contain different logic that would be implemented using polymorphism and abstract methods, for example:

```
public class User
{
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Role
{
    abstract void DoRoleSpecificStuff();
}

public class Vendor : Role
{
    public void DoRoleSpecificStuff()
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}

public class Employer : Role
{
    public void DoRoleSpecificStuff()
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}

public class Advertiser : Role
{
    public void DoRoleSpecificStuff()
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

If a User can have multiple Roles, consider using a Roles collection property:

```
public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

---

Otherwise, an **enumeration** using the `[Flags]` attribute could be fine, too, depending on whether you need to be able to assign multiple Roles:

```
public class User
{
    public Roles Roles { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum Roles
{
    Advertiser = 0x0,
    Employer = 0x1,
    Vendor = 0x2      
}
```

You would assign a combination of different roles as follows:

```
User user = new User
{
    Roles = Roles.Advertiser | Roles.Vendor;
};
```

That would make the User both an Advertiser and a Vendor, but not an Employer.

Comment: Um, no.  The OP asked about cases where a User may have multiple Roles.

Comment: Couldn't you have User.Roles, Roles being IEnumerable<Role> ?

Comment: @Jeffrey please review your comment. I was updating my answer when you typed.

Comment: @Mathias: Sure, depending on whether you need to be able to assign multiple roles. My updated answer contains that possibility, too.

Comment: @Marius, the [flags] thing is really cool.  it won't help me with this but I must keep it in mind!

Answer (score 2):

“I'm a * but I'm also a **” is known as Multiple Inheritance. C# does not support this, so you shouldn't be considering it.

Comment: Perhaps, but modeling the *concept* he's asking about does not require MI.

Comment: well... I don't know.  MI is useful to model upwards i.e. when a node on a taxonomy tree belongs to multiple roots, however (I could be wrong), in my case inheritance is lateral; in other words Employee and Vendor are actually siblings in the taxonomy

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed composition over inheritance here, but it's more like this if a single user can have multiple roles.

If there are relatively few roles, a 'parking lot' analogous to an outer join result may work.  In this pattern, no `Role` base class is required.

```
class User
{
    // all of these may be null if not applicable
    VendorRole VendorRole { get; set; }
    EmployeeRole EmployeeRole { get; set; }
    AdvertiserRole AdvertiserRole { get; set; }
}
```

If a user may have multiple instances of a single role, a collection pops up:

```
class User
{
    // all of these may be null if not applicable
    VendorRole VendorRole { get; set; }
    EmployeeRole EmployeeRole { get; set; }
    ICollection<AdvertiserRole> AdvertiserRoles { get; }
}
```

Alternatively, if there may be a messy pile of roles, if roles get added dynamically, or what have you, you'll need a collection and a base type.  If Entity Framework is involved, though, dynamically added roles seem unlikely to me.

```
class User
{
    ICollection<Role> Roles;
}
```